# Find the probability that the product of 3 different natural numbers less than 25 is divisible by 4

Tags: probability

> By less than 25 I meant a,b,c<25 where a,b,c are the natural numbers

I am aware of a similar question on this site but the solution involves modulo mathematics, something which I am not quite comfortable with. I would like to solve with a more classical approach

I divided the possibilities into two cases

1. There are at **least** 2 numbers which have exactly one power of 2 as their factors ie. 2,6,10,14,18
2. At least one number which is a multiple of 4

now counting these cases isn’t a challenge, but I am not able to account for the inevitable overcounting while using classical counting methods. Since these are products there are multiple combinations of numbers which will give the same product and I don’t know how to eliminate the over counts

Comment: There are 2024 possible products.  It may be simpler to solve the complementary problem:  how many products contain _no more than one_ factor of 2?

Comment: Clarification requested: Are you asking for the probability that three positive integers $a,b,c$ that are chosen at random happen to be such that $[(a\times b \times c) - 25]$ is divisible by $4$?

Comment: Re previous comment, assuming that my interpretation is correct, the chances of all 3 random numbers being odd is $(1/8)$.  The product can't be congruent to $1 \pmod{4}$ unless all three random numbers are odd.  Therefore, the problem is reduced to assuming that $a,b,c$ are all odd [chance $= (1/8)$] and then computing the chance that the product of 3 random odd numbers is $\equiv 1\pmod{4}.$

Comment: I may have misunderstood the statement as "natural numbers less _than_ 25"; I will withdraw my comment if the question is as **user2661923** asks.

Comment: @user2661923 no I meant the natural numbers can be chosen from [1,25)

Answer (score 1):

You could try complementation.
The only way the product of three numbers is *not* divisible by $4$ if it has at most 1 even number not divisible by $4$.
Now we count the number of ways of this.
For this note there are 12 odd numbers and 12 even numbers.
Can you complete the solution from here?

Comment: You want to choose 3 odd numbers, or 2 odd numbers and an even number that's not a multiple of 4